# What is the difference between dsPIC30F 2023 and dsPIC30F 2023-30I/PT

Tags: microcontroller, pic, integrated-circuit

I am new to PCB design and microcontroller programming. I want to start a project of a digital SMPS for the bench and I have chosen the DSPIC30F2023 as a controller for this purpose, but I cannot understand what is the difference between DSPIC30F2023 and DSPIC30F2023-30I/PT. What is the "-30I/PT" extension? Does it mean anything, or do it have something to do with the manufacture package?

Answer (score 1):

You can read it right off [the datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/70000178d.pdf), page 283:

[image]

Note that the "30" means the *speed* and that the "I" means an *industrial* temperature range. The "PT" means a *TQFP* package.

That page is a complete ordering system in a bottle!

So the main difference, with respect to your title question, is that the "dsPIC30F2023" is a device. But it does *not* specify the IC stepping (that's the *revision level* on the chart), so it specifies any version of the IC including the first edition and any and all subsequent "fixes" that have since been made to it. It doesn't specify whether it is delivered on tape or reel, the temperature range, the packaging, etc. A more specific part number specifies more of that.

For example, if there is a silicon bug in the first revision ("A") and it is an important silicon bug you want to avoid and it was fixed on the third revision of the IC ("C"), then you would want to specify at least "C" and maybe later as the IC to get. MicroSo the dsPIC30F2020C might be the important part you make sure you get. As an example. If interested in the steppings of this chip, see their [dsPIC30F1010/202X Family Silicon Errata and Data Sheet Clarification](https://www.microchip.com/content/dam/mchp/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/Errata/80000391b.pdf).

Out of curiosity (I'm very much a supporter of Microchip parts because of how well Microchip has supported me as a customer in the past), why did you decide on the dsPIC30F family of parts for your task? I'm very curious what it is that caused you to move in that direction. What considerations were important in making that decision? (And I'm just a hobbyist and I don't get paid to ask these questions. I really am *just curious*.)

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your concern about my project. My design  is about  a digital smps ,i first got a taste of what i need  in respect to components and schematics  that i have to use , e.g( converters ,the microprocessor ) and then i took the decision to collaborate with the microchip because of having more analytical documentation , and it uses the mplab x ide also easy for someone who needs , information being more accessible (compared to other companies with similar dsc's ) .

Comment: @ΝτίνοςΤσακαλάκης Are you fine, these days? Hope everything is going okay. Best wishes!